# Clean call api from client, with good practice

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on architecture where I can have any client + server API. I need to call API as clean as possible and get, post, put any object I want to.

For me, it is important to have clean secure code with good practice. This is how I implemented it and I would like you to help me to improve this code.

Some of questions are:

1. Should I return `HttpResponseMessage` from API (and why). Or is it ok to return list or object that I need?
2. Should I return anything from 'post' and 'put' or leave it just void?
3. Are `HttpClientFactory` and `JsonContentFactory` ok names for this classes? Is this factory at all?
4. Should I return some `HttpStatusCode` Enumeration from API in some case? I looks to me that I get good status code without setting anything in API. But is some cased on interner I saw that they set status code in response.
5. What is best way to handle exceptions in API?

**Call API from client:**

```
 public class WorkItemService : IWorkItemService
    {
        public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>> GetAllWorkItems()
        {
            IEnumerable<WorkItemDto> result = null;
            using (var client = HttpClientFactory.GetClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync("api/WorkItem");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>>(content);
                }
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new Exception((int)response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public async Task AddWorkItem(WorkItemDto item)
        {
            using (var client = HttpClientFactory.GetClient())
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync("api/WorkItem", JsonContentFactory.CreateJsonContent(item));
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new Exception((int)response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task UpdateWorkItem(WorkItemDto item)
        {
            using (var client = HttpClientFactory.GetClient())
            {
                var response = await client.PutAsync("api/WorkItem", JsonContentFactory.CreateJsonContent(item));
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new Exception((int)response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**`HttpClient` helper:**

```
  public static class HttpClientFactory
    {
        public static HttpClient GetClient()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1431");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return client;
        }
    }
```

StringContent helper:

```
 public static class JsonContentFactory
    {
        public static StringContent CreateJsonContent(object obj)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            var content = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return content;
        }
    }
```

**API:**

```
  public class WorkItemController : ApiController
    {
        private IWorkItemService workItemService;
        private MappingEngine mapperToEntity;
        private MappingEngine mapperToDomain;

        public WorkItemController(IWorkItemService workItemService, IMapperConfiguration mapperConfiguration)
        {
            this.workItemService = workItemService;
            this.mapperToEntity = mapperConfiguration.GetMapper(MapperType.DTOToEntity);
            this.mapperToDomain = mapperConfiguration.GetMapper(MapperType.EntityToDTO);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>> Get()
        {
            var allWorkItems = await workItemService.GetAllWorkItems();
            var allWorkItemsDTO = allWorkItems.Select(item => mapperToDomain.Map<WorkItem, WorkItemDto>(item)).ToList();
            return allWorkItemsDTO;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task Post([FromBody]WorkItemDto item)
        {
            var itemEntity = mapperToEntity.Map<WorkItemDto, WorkItem>(item);
            await workItemService.Add(itemEntity);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public async Task Put([FromBody]WorkItemDto workItem)
        {
            var itemEntity = mapperToEntity.Map<WorkItemDto, WorkItem>(workItem);
            await workItemService.Update(itemEntity);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

**Design**

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>>(content);
            }
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception((int)response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
```

These two if statements can be merged together using an `else`.

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>>(content);
            }
else
            {
                throw new Exception((int)response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
```

`"api/WorkItem"` is a magic string. Refactor this to a constant or instance variable with a good name.

By keeping `"http://localhost:1431"` as a hard-coded string you prevent yourself from ever being able to host the service separately. Consider putting it in a config file somewhere and reading it at runtime.

I cannot see any code branch that allows this to return null, so why are you initializing the result to null in the first place?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>> GetAllWorkItems()
    {
        IEnumerable<WorkItemDto> result = null;
        using (var client = HttpClientFactory.GetClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("api/WorkItem");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>>(content);
            }
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception((int)response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Instead, simply return the value when you have it.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>> GetAllWorkItems()
    {
        using (var client = HttpClientFactory.GetClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("api/WorkItem");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>>(content);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception((int)response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Exceptions**

```
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception((int)response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
```

Don't throw generic Exception types, use a more explicit type that explains what went wrong, don't just leave it to the exception message to explain because that makes it so much harder to catch.

**Var**

Your usage of implicit typing is great for most of the code, but you've got this line.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

That should be

```
var client = new HttpClient();
```

With style guides, consistency is more important than whether you do or do not follow a particular rule.

**Naming**

Your parameter naming is inconsistent.

```
public async Task Post([FromBody]WorkItemDto item)

public async Task Put([FromBody]WorkItemDto workItem)
```

Comment: Thank for help. This are all good sugestions. I updated my post with some questions that I still have.

Answer (score 7):

@Nick already has covered some important stuff, so I'd add my two cents.

Nick pointed out that :

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>>(content);
}
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    throw new Exception((int)response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
}
```

is weird. You can switch it for a `else`, but you can also remove the `else` entirely if you **reverse your condition**. Meaning :

```
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    throw new Exception((int)response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
}

string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>>(content);
```

This way you **reduce the nesting** and you **improve readability**.

Also, instead of throwing `Exception`, consider **throwing a custom exception**. You always need the same format :

```
(int)response.StatusCode + "-" + response.StatusCode.ToString()
```

Well, why don't you create an exception that works with this? Something like `ApiCallFailedException` (You might have a more appropriate/domain-specific exception name!) :

```
class ApiCallFailedException : ApplicationException
{
    public ApiCallFailedException(??? statusCode)
    {
        Message = $"{(int)StatusCode} - {StatusCode}";
    }
}
```

<strike>Now, see what I did there? I don't know the type for `response`, because you used `var` at a moment where we can't figure the type by reading.</strike>

@Heslasher pointed in comments that `response` wouldn't be a good paramter for the exception and it's true. Doing this you introduce a bond between two classes that shouldn't know each other. So instead I passed the `StatusCode`, but I don't know what's the type!

`var` should be used *only* when you can tell the type by reading the code. Ex :

```
var someCode = "550032423"; //good
var foobar = GetFooBar(); //bad, what is foobar?
```

We can **extract constants** out of your code. The best example possible is `"api/WorkItem"`. What if it happened to change? You'd need to change it at three places. You might forget one and boom, you introduced a bug.

How do we fix this? With a constant!

```
const string workItemApi = "api/WorkItem";
```

You can then reuse this constant everywhere in your code without fear of breaking something if it happened to change.

This : `"http://localhost:1431"` should be extracted from a configuration file (Like the `app.config`). What if you had to change the port or the host of your application? You'd need to recompile your application. This isn't good.

It might be a mistake when you copied your code here, but your indentation is off :

```
public class WorkItemController : ApiController
  {
```

should be :

```
public class WorkItemController : ApiController
{
```

Finally, you could set your private member to `readonly` since they don't seem to be modifier inside your controller.

```
    private readonly IWorkItemService workItemService;
    private readonly MappingEngine mapperToEntity;
    private readonly MappingEngine mapperToDomain;
```

I don't know what mapping engine you use, but do you know about [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)? It's really awesome.

Comment: Nice catch on reversing the condition.

Comment: Using a custom exception is the way to go, but the `response` shouldn't be passed to the constructor because it is tightly coupling the exception to the response where the calling client maybe isn't aware of the `response`.